# Does There Exist a Continuous Surjection from $(0, 1)$ to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

For the reverse part it is not true as $S^1$ is compact but $(0, 1)$ is not compact and we know

Continuous image of a compact set is compact.

But in this problem we cannot use this argument as $(0, 1)$  is not compact.  How should I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it does. For example 
$$ (0,1) \ni x \mapsto (\cos (4\pi x), \sin(4\pi x)) \in \mathbb S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$$

Comment: The same function will work for [0, 1],  right?

Comment: @Pradip Yes it does.

Answer (score 3):

Covering $S^1$ more than once provides a continuous surjection from $(0,1)$ to it:
$$f(x)=e^{7ix}$$
In particular, $f(2\pi/7)=1$.

Comment: $2\pi \notin (0,1)$. I think you've meant $f(\frac{2\pi}{7}) = 1$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Yes, thank you for the thinko.