# Does There exist a Continuous Surjection from $S^1$ to $[0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Obviously there is no homeomorphism between them.

As both of them compact and connected I am facing difficulty to show such continuous surjection not exist.  Actually I have a feeling that there does not exist such continuous surjection but how?

Comment: [The converse question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281384/357390) is put here fore reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the map $(\cos x, \sin x) \mapsto \cos x$, this is a continuous surjection onto $[-1,1]$. Since $[-1,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ via $x \mapsto \frac{1+x}{2}$, composition gives the desired map.

Answer (score 2):

If the interval had been $(0,1)$, there would be no surjection because any homeomorphism from a compact space is compact.

However, since the interval here is *closed*, we can simply project and obtain a surjection. If we write the points of $S^1$ as $e^{ix}$, then a surjection is given by
$$f(e^{ix})=\frac{1+\cos x}2$$